# There is not set of "dominated set".

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set $A$ is said to be dominated by "B" if there exist an injective function $f:A\rightarrow B$.

> How can I prove that there is not a set $A$ such that for every set there exist one member in $A$ which dominate it.

Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you rephrase the question it isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider powerset of the union of all the sets in $A$. You can prove no set in $A$ dominates that.